# ANTLR4: Comma not detected as unicode char

Tags: antlr4

I have a language where i want to parse unicode characters. Those characters are presided by %.
So this text: `%,`, this: `a=&,` or even this: `(a,b)=%,` should detect the ',' as unicode character.

It does so until i add the pattern for (a,b).

Here the code that works without (a,b):

```
grammar example;

test: expr | decl;

decl: (VARIABLE_DECLARATION? ID ) '=' expr
    ;

VARIABLE_DECLARATION
    : 'public' | 'private'
    ;


expr: unicode;

unicode: '%' CHAR;
ID:  ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'!') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_'|'!'|'?')*;
CHAR:     // Other_Punctuation
        '\u{0021}'..'\u{0023}'   // [!..#] Basic Latin
     |  '\u{0025}'..'\u{0027}'   // [%..'] Basic Latin
     |  '\u{002a}'             // [*] Basic Latin
     |  '\u{002c}'             // [,] Basic Latin
     |  '\u{002e}'..'\u{002f}'   // [.../] Basic Latin
     |  '\u{003a}'..'\u{003b}'   // [:..;] Basic Latin
     |  '\u{003f}'..'\u{0040}'   // [?..@] Basic Latin
     |  '\u{005c}'             // [\] Basic Latin
;
```

with this i get the following error: mismatched input ',' expecting CHAR

```
    grammar example;

    test: expr | decl;

    decl: (VARIABLE_DECLARATION? ID | '('ID (',' ID)* ')' ) '=' expr
    ;

    VARIABLE_DECLARATION
    : 'public' | 'private'
    ;


    expr: unicode;

unicode: '%' CHAR;
ID:  ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'!') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_'|'!'|'?')*;
CHAR:     // Other_Punctuation
        '\u{0021}'..'\u{0023}'   // [!..#] Basic Latin
     |  '\u{0025}'..'\u{0027}'   // [%..'] Basic Latin
     |  '\u{002a}'             // [*] Basic Latin
     |  '\u{002c}'             // [,] Basic Latin
     |  '\u{002e}'..'\u{002f}'   // [.../] Basic Latin
     |  '\u{003a}'..'\u{003b}'   // [:..;] Basic Latin
     |  '\u{003f}'..'\u{0040}'   // [?..@] Basic Latin
     |  '\u{005c}'             // [\] Basic Latin
;
```

how can i solve that?

Answer (score 1):

`'\u{002c}'` does indeed match `,` (though I don't understand why you'd write it as a Unicode escape instead of just `','`). The problem is that you're also using `','` as a literal in your parser rules. This implicitly defines a lexer rule that matches only `,`.

Lexer rules that are implicitly defines through the use of literals have higher priority than named lexer rules, so whenever the lexer sees a comma, it chooses to create a `','` token instead of a `CHAR` token.

To fix this I suggest you remove `,` from the set of characters matched by `CHAR` and instead use `(CHAR | ',')` wherever you want to allow both. You could even define a non-terminal `char: CHAR | ',';` and use that.